# Jenkins job HTML output, it's possible to render it as HTML page

Tags: jenkins

My jobs generate logs and result with html tags.
However I see only plain text. I would like to render them as HTML

Comment: Have you checked if a plugin is available for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HTML test report plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/htmlpublisher) with some custom script to write job logs to file.

Here is the simple example

```
 set +x
 # echo some html tag with content
 echo "<html> <body> <h1> Heading HTML test </h1> </body> <html>"
 # read the current job logs and write it log.thml to consider as job report
 cat ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log >> log.html
```

also will suggest cleaning workspace after the job is done.

[image]
speicfy path for html report

[image]
you will see report in the dashbaord

[image]

Test report view 
[image]

Comment: Oh, ok thx , I didn't understand how to use the plugin actually. However it doesn't work out of the box, on linux it gives a permssion error creating the report. Strange because it's a standard bitnami install and I don't want to mess up permissions...

Comment: you can run the comment with bitnami user or own test report with bitnami user.

Comment: ? what do you mean with "run the comment"?